# waitFor in ProcessBuilder does not working

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

I tried to open Outlook eml file and waiting when the user will close the window of the eml.
I using this code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command("cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "/wait", "outlook.exe",
        "/eml", "C:/test.eml");
p = pb.start();

try {
    if(p != null) {
        p.waitFor();
    }

} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Got an exception.", e);
    throw e;
} finally {
    logger.info("closing process...");
}
```

But it's not waiting until I close the eml window...
It's print "closing process..." before that.

What can I do?

---

**Update (30-Sep-2020):** new code based on first answers and comments:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("outlook.exe", "/eml", "email5704371022351125516.eml");
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Closing process...");
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64047162/edit) your question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). On the line 4, you have an identifier `p`, which is not defined in your code. Also, `ProcessBuilder#start()` throws a checked exception, which should be handled in `try` or thrown one level up.

Comment: Java will be quite happy to read from a path with / in place of \ but outlook probably won't like "C:/test.eml"

Comment: Why so complicated? why starting `cmd.exe` to run `start` to execute `outlook.exe`, why not simply executing `outlook.exe` directly?

Comment: @aschipfl Cannot run program "outlook.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Try to provide the full path to `outlook.exe`. *N. B.:* I reverted your edit and implemented your new code in an update section of your question, because otherwise, the already posted answers would no longer fit to the question…

Comment: @aschipfl the outlook now open fine but no wait to eml will close.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to launch CMD to start outlook though you may need to fully qualify the pathname to outlook:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("outlook.exe", "/eml", "C:\\test.eml");
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
logger.info("Closing process...");
```

Also there is no need to check `p!=null` as `start()` will have thrown an exception or given back a process handle.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "outlook.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: If outlook is not in your path you will need to put the full pathname in as first parameter. See value of `System.getenv("Path")`.

Comment: but its for users... i dont know if they have path or not

Comment: there is option that i can add it dynamically to path with java? because its for users not for me

Comment: i add to the path, its working but still its not wait for that i will close the eml file...

Comment: Are you now launching with arguments `"outlook.exe", "/eml", "test.eml"` ? You could try checking value returned from `waitFor()` though it always gives 0 back after waiting for exit when I try it.